# Mallocing nested structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc

If if write the following code:

```
struct _one
{
    int x;
};
struct _two
{
    struct _one one;
};
struct _three
{
   struct _two two;
};
```

Then in `main` I call a user defined functions that malloces the `_three` structure, and returns the pointer to `main`, is the `x` variable in the heap?
Because you access it this way:

```
three->two.one.x;
```

Because when you access it with the dot operator, that usually means it is static, as opposed to dynamic. The `->` operator usually means that it is dynamically allocated. I was wondering if something weird was going on behind the scenes (maybe).

Comment: The `x` variable is stored on the stack, but its value is a memory address on the heap, but essentially yes.

Comment: There is no `x` variable.  If you do `struct _three *w = malloc(sizeof *w)`, then you have a variable `w` and a member `w->two.one.x`.

Comment: Also there is the "as if" rule... so any transformation made by the compiler is acceptable for as long as the program behaves *as if* `x` was in dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Heap“ is a colloquialism for the memory managed by the memory management routines (`malloc`, `free`, and `family`). At one time, that memory may have been managed with a heap structure, but modern routines are more complicated. A proper term for this memory is “dynamically allocated memory.”

Generally, whether the routines use a heap or other data structure to manage memory, they have a database of memory available to be allocated. For example, they may have a list (whether it is in a heap, tree, hash table, bit map, some other structure, or some combination of structures) of blocks that were once allocated by have since been freed, so they can be given out again. Or the list may include memory that is available because a large amount was obtained from the operating system to satisfy an earlier request, but only part of it was needed for the specific request, so the remainder is available for future requests.

What this means for your question, is the member `x` (and the structure it is in) in the heap, is that when memory is allocated, it is actually **removed** from the heap or other database. It is no longer available to give out, so it is not in the database of available memory.

This means memory you have allocated is not in the heap.

At that point, it is your program’s responsibility to keep track of that memory and to release it with `free` at an appropriate time. That will return it to the database of available memory. (An appropriate time might be never, if your program finishes its job and is exiting. In general-purpose multiuser operating systems, there is no need to free allocated memory when exiting; the operating system will reclaim it.)

However, the memory you have allocated is dynamically allocated memory, and it might be consider “part of” the pool of such memory in some sense. That is, even though it is not currently part of the database of available memory, it is part of all of the memory that is dynamically allocated and freed.

More particularly, your structure `struct _three` is defined to include a member `two` of type `struct _two`, and that includes a member `one` of type `struct _one`, and that includes a member `x` of type `int`. All of these form one `struct _three` object. C does not treat them as separate things that can be split apart in memory and managed separately. Only if you have pointers can a structure have a member that connects to a separate thing in memory. In that case, your program will be allocating that memory separately; it will have to use `malloc` or a related routine to get memory for that separate thing and set the pointer member to point to that other memory.